# Why does this Keras conv2D layer give an error

Tags: keras, neural-network, tf.keras, mnist

I am learning using Keras for neural network applications. I have started experimenting with the mnist dataset first and have managed to make a simple NN with dense layers and get a decent result. I am currently trying to incorporate a 2D convolution layer as well, but keep running into an error. The code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

import numpy as np

training_data, testing_data = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(path = "mnist.npz")

image_data, image_classifiers = training_data

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (28, 28)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = 3, use_bias = True, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (None, 28,28,1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))
```

The error I get is:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv2d_12" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 10)

The images are 28 by 28 arrays with values from 0 to 255 (grayscale, single channel).

I have tried several things such as not specifying input shape, not having an input layer... but I can't get it to work and I don't understand the logic behind it..

Comment: This code is incomplete, it produces a different error, Syntax errors due to unclosed strings

Comment: Apologies, fixed the missing bit of code

Comment: Once you correct the strings errors, adjust your input shapes. Do not include the batch dimension while specifying the shape. Your shape is `input_shape=(28,28,1)`, assuming a (height, width, depth) order.

Comment: Adjusted both input layer and convolution layer input shapes to (28,28,1), same error remains I'm afraid

Comment: I think you are still missing code, as this code does not call fit or something that would trigger the error.